# Oracle stored procedure, split VARCHAR and handle cases

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, split

I have a little trouble doing this, wish someone can help.

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILTER_COPY(
        vOrigen IN VARCHAR2,
        sListadoClientes__ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
       )
        IS
        vParam VARCHAR2(10);
        vQuery_final VARCHAR2(2500);
BEGIN
    DECLARE BEGIN
        FOR i IN
     (SELECT regexp_substr(vOrigen ,'[^,]+', 1, level) AS params FROM dual
             CONNECT BY regexp_substr(vOrigen, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
         LOOP
         vParam := i.params;
         END LOOP;
    CASE (vOrigen)
        WHEN 'CALLCENTER' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDCALL as indice, NOMBRE as nombre FROM CALL ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'PAIS' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT CODE as indice, NAME as nombre FROM PAIS WHERE CODE IN ('''|| 'CAN' ||''',''' || 'USA' ||''') ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'HOTEL' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT HOTEL_ID as indice,NOMBRE as nombre FROM HOTEL WHERE TIPO = '' || ROYAL || '' ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'NOTA' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDNOTA as indice, TIPONOTA as nombre FROM NOTAS ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'DEPARTAMENTO' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDDEPTO as indice, DEPTO as nombre FROM DEPATRAMENTO WHERE MESSAGE = 1 ORDER BY 1';

    END CASE;
    -- query_final:='SELECT DUMMY  FROM DUAL';
    OPEN sListadoClientes__ FOR vQuery_final;
     --select vParam as CLIENT from dual;
  END;
END;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to handle when the IN parameter "vOrigen" is just a case or if is two params that i need to split to accomplish, the origin of this stored procedure is in the 'HOTEL' case because I need to get the ORIGIN to complete the select statement.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your scenario is a little hard to understand. Please add some examples showing what output you expect from various values of `vOrigen`.

Comment: In this procedure are two cases, one whet the application send just one string in vOrigen like "NOTA" or "CALLCENTER", the second case is that the application send "HOTEL, CUN", that "HOTEL" is the case in the switch statement and CUN that is the origin that i want to put in the select case, I just need to handle that two options, tell me if i don't explain my self very well, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When vOrigen is "HOTEL, CUN" and you want to use "HOTEL" in case and "CUN" in a select you can try something like this:

```
declare
    vQuery_final VARCHAR2(2500);
    vOrigen varchar2(2000);
    type param_table is table of varchar2(100) index by PLS_INTEGER;
    t_param param_table;
BEGIN
    vOrigen := 'HOTEL, CUN';

    FOR i IN (SELECT regexp_substr(vOrigen ,'[^,]+', 1, level) AS params, level as nr FROM dual
         CONNECT BY regexp_substr(vOrigen, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
     LOOP
        t_param(i.nr) := trim(i.params);--delete spaces
        dbms_output.put_line(i.nr||' param='||t_param(i.nr));
     END LOOP;

    CASE (t_param(1))
        WHEN 'CALLCENTER' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDCALL as indice, NOMBRE as nombre FROM CALLCENTER ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'PAIS' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT CODE as indice, NAME as nombre FROM PAIS WHERE CODE IN ('''|| 'CAN' ||''',''' || 'USA' ||''') ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'HOTEL' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT HOTEL_ID as indice,NOMBRE as nombre FROM HOTEL WHERE TIPO = ''' || t_param(2) || ''' ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'NOTA' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDNOTA as indice, TNOTA as nombre FROM NOTAS ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'DEPARTAMENTO' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDDEPTO as indice, DEPTO as nombre FROM DEPARTAMENTO WHERE MESSAGE = 1 ORDER BY 1';

        ELSE vQuery_final:= 'select 1 from dual';
    END CASE;

    dbms_output.put_line('vQuery_final='||vQuery_final);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to split the parameters combinations "NOTA" or "HOTEL, CUN"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILTER_COPY(
        vOrigen IN VARCHAR2,
        sListadoClientes__ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
       )
        IS
   vParam VARCHAR2(10);
   vQuery_final VARCHAR2(2500);
   v_param1  varchar2(10);
   v_param2  varchar2(10);
BEGIN

SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (vOrigen, '[^,]+', 1, 1) 
INTO v_param1
from dual;

SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (vOrigen, '[^,]+', 1, 2)
INTO v_param2
from dual;

    CASE (v_param1)
        WHEN 'CALLCENTER' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDCALLC as indice, NOMBRE as nombre FROM CALLCENTER ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'PAIS' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT CODE as indice, NAME as nombre FROM PAIS WHERE CODE IN ('''|| 'CAN' ||''',''' || 'USA' ||''') ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'HOTEL' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT HOTEL_ID as indice,NOMBRE as nombre FROM HOTEL WHERE TIPO = ''' || v_param2 || ''' ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'NOTA' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDTNOTA as indice, TIPONOTA as nombre FROM NOTAS ORDER BY 1';

        WHEN 'DEPARTAMENTO' THEN vQuery_final:= 'SELECT IDDEPTO as indice, DEPTO as nombre FROM DEPARTAMENTO WHERE MESSAGE = 1 ORDER BY 1';

        ELSE vQuery_final:= 'select 1 from dual';
    END CASE;

END;
```